# Train Tensorflow object detection model for Coral TPU

Tags: tensorflow, tpu

My config PC system:

**ubuntu 18.04
Tensorflow 1.15.0
Cuda 10.0
Cudnn 7.6.5
GPU GTX 1080 Nvidia**

I want to train the ssd-mobile-v1/v2-quant-coco of TFOD models with NVIDIA GPU for Coral TPU.
I have some questions:

**1-** Is it possible to train these models of TFOD API on NVIDIA GPUs?

**2-** Is there a difference between training results with NVIDIA GPUs and Google TPUs under the same situations? If do, Please a more explaining about the differences.

**3-** Is it possible to do quantification-away training with NVIDIA GPUs for INT8? as same as accuracy TPU quantification-away training?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Trying to train on GPU for deployment on Coral using the tutorials and getting a segmentation fault.